# How to figure out which trend model is best for our dataset in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop, trendline

I have date and measure fields in Tableau. I know the types of Tableau trend lines.

As we have 5 types of trend lines: Linear, Logarithmic, Exponential, Polynomial, and Power trend lines and their formulas.

When we click describe trend line, it shows statistical values but it won't show whether we selected the correct trend line or not.

How to figure out which trend model is best for our dataset?

Please share if there are any simple points (prerequisites) to consider/learn.

When I drag the Trend line to the workbook, it is showing the possible trend lines. For example, my dataset shows possible trend lines are - linear, exponential, and power trend lines.

But I am trying to figure out which one is suitable for my dataset.